# Is removing actionListener necessary when you disable the button?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a `minesweeper` in `Java` with Swing and I figured it'd be a fast way to get "rid" of a button that was clicked by using

`JButton.setEnabled(false);` (with a proper icon too, of course).

But do I have to remove all the listeners connected to this button later or is it enough and I can just forget about the said button then?

Comment: No need of removing listeners, in-case, in particular use case if you want to re enable buttons, and if you have removed listeners. Then your button will become useless. Better don't remove it

Comment: please to delete this question, use a new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 different questions, one in your title, and one in your description.

> Is removing actionListener necessary when you disable the button?

As stated in the previous comments, no.

```
But do I have to remove all the listeners connected to this button later...
```

Yes, if you have other kinds of listeners.  For example, a MouseListener will still fire if the button is disabled.  Usually, there is no need for a MouseListener on JButton, but there may be in some corner cases.  I'm not sure about the other types of listeners that can be added to a JButton.

Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Oh, that's a useful info about the MouseListener. Thanks a lot :)